# How is it possible in Android to call a non-static method in one class without an instance?

Tags: java, android

As far as I know, in Android programming it is possible to call a non-static method in one class without an instance. For example,

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {
    private Textview tvSample;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

        findViews();
    }

    public void findViews() {
        tvSample = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSample);
    }
}
```

So the thing is, that the findViews() method works without declaring a variable even though it is a non-static method. I have known so far that in Java, you should declare a method static unless you want to use it with an instance. So the example code does not work.

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 4;
        printOnConsole(a);
    }

    public void printOnConsole(int a) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

in order to make the code above, you should add static to the printOnConsole() method.

I'm super new to the programming world, and thus there might be some critical points that I'm missing at this moment, so please don't vote my question not valuable and give me some answers if possible.

Thank you so much in advance..

Comment: You don't understand the meaning of static - non-static context. In your second sample, you cannot call `printOnConsole(int a)` like that because you are trying to invoke an instance method (*non-static*) rather than a class method (*static*) from a static context, which is not allowed without the instance you're calling it on. Read [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) to get a grip on the topic.

Comment: General rule: Static methods can call static methods and non-static methods of objects. Non-static methods can call static methods, non-static methods of objects and non-static methods of the class they are declared in and its superclasses.

Comment: What makes you think there isn't an instance when `findViews` is called? It's called from a different instance method.

Comment: `findViews()` is the same as `this.findViews()`, so there is a "variable". Non-static methods can only be called on objects.

Comment: Your first example works because `onCreate` is not static - it actually belongs to an instance of SampleActivity.

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy Yes of course I cannot call the printOnConsole() method without an instance. But what I want to find out is how it is possible in Android to do so. I have found a few codes in Android in which the non-static methods are included in one class and they are called without an instance.

Comment: @designspired Please give us an example what you are referring to.

Comment: @still_learning I just read your comment and made another sample code in Java, and now I understand. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @designspired Like I said, you don't understand how this works. Read the article on the link I included above first. Android works the same way as Java, because it is Java in fact (*we don't talk about the VM which runs the whole thing nor the compiled bytecode, only the language used to write programs*).

Comment: @designspired You are welcome, I tried to explain it in detail in an answer.

Comment: @designspired It *isn't* possible. There's an instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> findViews() method works without declaring a variable even though it is a non-static method

The compiler expands `findViews()` to `this.findViews()`, so there is a "variable". Non-static methods can only be called on objects (e.g. `this`).

As a general rule, keep this in mind: Static methods can call static methods and non-static methods on objects. Non-static methods can call static methods, non-static methods of objects and non-static methods of the class they are declared in and its superclasses.

---

To prove this, compile a class with these methods:

```
public void oneNonStaticMethod() {
    otherNonStaticMethod();
}
public void otherNonStaticMethod() {
    // Nothing
}
```

`oneNonStaticMethod` will be compiled to this:

```
0: aload_0           // Load "this" onto stack
1: invokevirtual #2  // Call otherNonStaticMethod:()V on "this"
4: return            // return
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Android code, you are **within an object**, namely `SampleActivity`.

This is why the method `findViews()` is found: Android creates this object for you whenever the activity is started. Many things are done in the background for you in Android. You just need to fill in the missing pieces, so to say.

In your second example, you are using pure Java. You have to create all the objects yourself inside the `main(String[] argv)` function. As you did not do that, and you are not within an object, the call to `printOnConsole()` fails.